# Why does my array give huge initial values instead of 0?

Tags: arrays

This is part of a code that I wrote, but for some reason the numbers were quite off.
So I did some testing and it turns out the initial value of the array "counter" is all over the place.
What is going on here?
Note: I know the code is not optimal but I was just doing some debugging to see what was going on.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int s1, s2, s3; cin>>s1>>s2>>s3;
    int counter[81];
    int temp;
    
    for(int i=1;i<=s1;i++){
        for(int x=1;x<=s2;x++){
            for(int k=1;k<=s3;k++){
                temp=i+x+k;
                counter[temp]++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no guarantees given about the initial values of the array. Its just full of all the junk that happens to be lying around at that location in memory

Comment: But shouldn't the initial value of an undefined array be 0? I have never had a problem with this before. Why would this be occurring now?

Comment: to your first question the answer is no. There are no guarantees, the values are 'indeterminate'. You may have never encountered this before simply because you were lucky, or maybe if you were using `static` or file scope variables before.

Comment: When I initialized the array as a global array, it worked. Is there any reason for this?
It should be noted that I am doing this on a coding problem website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you get from uninitialised variables differs according to the 'storage duration' of the variable.

Automatic storage duration variables are for example those declared as non-static local objects, like local variables inside functions. The storage for these is allocated at the beginning of the enclosing scope, and unless you initialise them, their values are 'indeterminate'. That is, you cannot count on them being `0`.

Variables in the global scope or declared as `static` have static storage duration. In this case their storage is allocated when the program starts, and there are guarantees on their uninitialised values.

This [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) goes into more detail. But the difference can be seen in summary by inspecting the output of these 2 programs:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

  int array[10];  // automatic duration
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cout << array[i] << endl;
}
```

Which is *not* guaranteed to print`0`s. and:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int array[10];  // static duration

int main () {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cout << array[i] << endl;
}
```

Which *is* guaranteed to print `0`s.